# Getting ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined while reading a JSON object via a service in sibling component

Tags: angular, angular7

I have defined a service as below

dataservice.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoeDataService {

public storage: any;

constructor() { } 
}
```

In form-component.ts am importing that

```
import { LoeDataService } from '../loe-data.service';
```

I have declared as below,

```
private LoeData: LoeDataService,


onSubmit(){
this.LoeData.storage = {
  "duration" : this.durationOfService,
  "sdm" : this.offeringsForm.controls.sdm.value,
}
```

After submitting the form data, I will call the function to store the data as above and I pass this object to another component for further processing.

In the processcomponent.ts

```
export class ProcessFormData{
constructor(

public data: LoeDataService,


) { }
ngOnInit(){
calculate();
}

}
calculate(){
if (this.data.storage.sdm == 1){
 //truncated the code 
 }

}
```

providers were updated as below.

```
providers: [ 
LoeDataService
]
```

I am getting the error at the above condition, it says as below.

ng:///AppModule/proComponent_Host.ngfactory.js:5 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'sdm' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe `this.data.storage` is undefined. Give it an initial value:

```
public storage: any = {};
```

You also need to inject as `data` and not `Data` (be consistent with your casing).

Comment: I declared the data in the code (not Data) and declaring the initial value helped me clear the error. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need that part:

```
providers: [ 
  LoeDataService
]
```

because `LoeDataService` provided in root here:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoeDataService {
...
```

You can access it by `this.Data` (you're injecting your service as `Data` not `data`). Also initially, `storage` is `undefined` (until it get value after submitting), but you're trying to access it on `ngOnInit`. So you need to assign initial value to `storage`:

dataservice.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoeDataService {

  public storage: = {
    "duration": 0,
    "sdm": "",
  };

  constructor() { } 
}
```

form-component.ts:

```
private LoeData: LoeDataService,


onSubmit() {
  this.LoeData.storage.duration = this.durationOfService
  this.LoeData.storage.sdm = this.offeringsForm.controls.sdm.value
}
```

processcomponent.ts:

```
export class ProcessFormData {
  constructor(public Data: LoeDataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    calculate();
  }

  calculate() {
    // note that this runs only once
    // when component get initialized
    if (this.Data.storage.sdm == 1) {
      // truncated the code 
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: sorry it was a typo in the question. I have edited the question. I have declared it as  public data: LoeDataService in the code. I am using VisualStudio the moment I type this.Data.storage the editor will throw the error.